# How do you get an xml feed from teamcity 5.1 of the pinned builds?

Tags: teamcity

Looking to get an xml feed of just pinned builds. I see that I can filter on successful / unsuccessful builds, but can't find a flag / option to filter by pinned. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the Rest API from [TeamCity](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin)

You can load a list of all builds:

http://YOURSERVER/httpAuth/app/rest/builds

The result ist something like this:

```
<builds nextHref="/httpAuth/app/rest/builds?count=100&amp;start=100" count="100">
   <build id="4324" number="273" status="SUCCESS" buildTypeId="bt9" href="/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:4324" webUrl="http://YOURSERVER/viewLog.html?buildId=4324&amp;buildTypeId=bt9"/>
   <build id="4323" number="283" status="ERROR" buildTypeId="bt10" href="/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:4323" webUrl="http://YOURSERVER/viewLog.html?buildId=4323&amp;buildTypeId=bt10"/>
   <build id="4322" number="56" status="SUCCESS" buildTypeId="bt44" href="/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:4322" webUrl="http://YOURSERVER/viewLog.html?buildId=4322&amp;buildTypeId=bt44"/>
</builds>
```

By look at the href you can get detailed Info for this Build. And there is an attribute `pinned`

The count and the start position of the list of build can you control by adding GET Parameters like this: `?count=5&start=200`

If you want it for specific Projects or Project Configuratins you have to go this way:

With this API you can retrieve all Projects.
(use http://YOURSERVER/httpAuth/app/rest/projects)

With this info you can get the Configurations.
(example: http://YOURSERVER/httpAuth/app/rest/projects/id:project3)

Here you get the detail info about a specific configuration:
(example: http://YOURSERVER/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:bt17

And finally with this list you can get details of this build:
(example: http://YOURSERVER/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:4144

The result of the last call is something like this:

```
<build id="4271" number="151" status="SUCCESS" href="/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:4271" webUrl="http://YOURSERVER/viewLog.html?buildId=4271&amp;buildTypeId=bt2" personal="false" history="false" pinned="false">
<statusText>Tests passed: 177</statusText>
<buildType id="bt2" name="trunk Legacy" href="/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:bt2" projectName="Common" projectId="project2" webUrl="http://YOURSERVER/viewType.html?buildTypeId=bt2"/>
<startDate>20100923T082041+0200</startDate>
<finishDate>20100923T082320+0200</finishDate>
<agent name="buildagent" id="3" href="/httpAuth/app/rest/agents/id:3"/>
<tags/>
<properties>
    <property name="env.SvnSubDirectory" value="trunk"/>
</properties>
<revisions>
    <revision display-version="9335">
        <vcs-root href="/httpAuth/app/rest/vcs-roots/id:1,ver:1" name="Common"/>
    </revision>
</revisions>
<changes href="/httpAuth/app/rest/changes?build=id:4271" count="1"/>
<relatedIssues/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not what you asked for, but as I found this question when searching for a similar thing for Version 9:

On TeamCity 9, you can easily just access

https://teamcity.YOURCOMPANY.com/app/rest/builds?locator=pinned:true

Documentation: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildLocator